# I have constructed an array during the constructor of a class, is there a way to make it so every method recognises it?

Tags: java

In the constructor I've built an array and I'm trying to take the .length of that array in another function within the class but it doesn't take the same array even though it's the same name it says that the array is empty.

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

Your array should be an instance variable:

```
public class Example {

    // Private variables defined outside of a method/constructor can 
    // be used anywhere within the class but not outside of the class
    private String[] array;

    public Example() {
        array = new String[6];
    }

    public int length() {
        return array.length;
    }
}
```